# Angular Outlook add-in Binding issue in Taskpane

Tags: angular, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am new to Outlook add-in task pane. Created the add-in using yeoman generator. Default created application working fine with Command.ts code but the code from TaskPane is not executing. Angular data binding not working.

[image]

There is no change in manifest file. Its default created by generator. There is already generated command pane working fine but the task pane is having issue related to Angular I think.
I tried opening the https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html which working perfectly in browser but not working through add-in opened screen.

[image]

Adding the browser console results from outlook web view. There is no error.

[image]

taskpane.html

```html
<body class="ms-font-m ms-welcome">
    <h2 id="sideload-msg" className='ms-fontSize-su ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary'>Please sideload your addin to see app body.</h2>
    <app-home></app-home>
</body>
```

taskpane.ts

```js
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */
import "zone.js"; // Required for Angular
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import AppModule from "./app/app.module";

/* global console, document, Office */

Office.onReady(() => {
 

  // Bootstrap the app
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
});
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export default class AppComponent {
// constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
// }
   public welcomeMessage = "Welcome";
   async run() {
   /**
   * Insert your Outlook code here
   */
   // this.zone.run(()=>{
   this.welcomeMessage = "I am changed";
   // })    
   }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<header class="ms-welcome__header ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-u-fadeIn500">
    <img width="90" height="90" src="../../../assets/logo-filled.png" alt="Contoso Task Pane Add-in" title="Contoso Task Pane Add-in" />
    <h1 class="ms-fontSize-su ms-fontWeight-light ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary">{{welcomeMessage}}</h1>
</header>

<div role="button" class="ms-welcome__action ms-Button ms-Button--hero ms-u-slideUpIn20" (click)="run()">
        <span class="ms-Button-label">Run</span>
        <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronRight"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: What happens if you open the debugger from the task pane's Personality Menu?

Comment: Third screenshot is for console window when I open Task pane menu @RickKirkham

Comment: Are you trying this in "Outlook Desktop" (Windows) machine or in "Outlook Web"?

Comment: Tried both - Outlook Web with edge browser and outlook desktop.

Comment: Hi @Bh00shan, here is some documentation on developing Office Add-ins using Angular - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2

Comment: All the Issues related to Yeoman are tracked in the github repository Issues · OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Angular (github.com), Please create an issue there. Also, the team is already in process of updating the angular templates.